# How to use Struts 1.2.9 tags

Tags: javascript, struts-1

I am using Struts Version 1.2.9.
I have a requirement to add rows dynamically to a table using JavaScript which is working fine.

It looks like:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

   var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 

   rowCount += 1;      

   if(rowCount <= 5){
    var row = table.insertRow(3);   
    var col1html = "<label for='incomecategory'>Other Income:</label>";  
    var col2html = "<select id='incomecategory' name='income_category'><option value='' selected>Please Select</option><option value='rent'>Rent</option><option value='interestanddividends'>Interest and Dividends</option><option value='governmentbenefits'>Government Benefits</option><option value='other'>Other</option></select>";
    var col3html = "$<input type='text' name='incomevalue' id='incomevalue'/>";
    var col4html = "<select id='incomefrequency' name='income_frequency'><optgroup label='Per'><option value='perweek'>Per Week</option><option value='perfortnight'>Per Fortnight</option><option value='peryear'>Per Month</option><option value='peryear'>Per Year</option><option value='' selected>Per</option></select>";
    var col5html = "<input type='button' value='X' onclick='removeRow(this)'/>"

    var col1 = row.insertCell(0); col1.innerHTML=col1html;
    var col2 = row.insertCell(1); col2.innerHTML=col2html;
    var col3 = row.insertCell(2); col3.innerHTML=col3html;
    var col4 = row.insertCell(3); col4.innerHTML=col4html;
    var col5 = row.insertCell(4); col5.innerHTML=col5html;

   }else{

       alert('Reached maximum no of rows');
   }  

}
```

If you see carefully I have hardcoded all the HTML tags to build a row, but I want to instead use struts tags in creating rows.

Comment: You can't; JS is executed on the client, S1 tags are evaluated on the server. Why specifically do you need to use the S1 tags? Can't you build the equivalent HTML? Your other option is to return HTML fragments and add those to the DOM, but that has associated issues as well (like S1 tags not playing nice outside of a form).

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks for replying...Posted code actually builds the equivalent html. But not sure how to pass the values, after user makes selection and inputs the values in the newly added row, and clicks on submit button. Each dynamic row will have same structure - col1-label,col2-dropdown,col3-text,col4-dropdown,col5-delete button. 
Really appreciate any help in this regard.